# Dynamically declare and assign variables in a loop

Tags: python

How can achieve the following: I want to create unique dynamic variables in a for loop `self."INSERT DYNAMIC VARIABLE HERE"`

```
list = [box1, box2, box3]
for value in list:
 self."" = Button()
```

Comment: Use a dictionary instead. (And don't use the built-in `list` as a name.)

Comment: Yes probably use dictionary as `self.variables = dict()` and keep updating it in the loop like, `self.variables[<name>] = value`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `exec`, **but it's highly not recommended see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)**:

```
l = [box1, box2, box3]
for value in l:
    exec(f"self.{value} = Button()")
```

I would recommend you to just store it in a dictionary:

```
l = [box1, box2, box3]
self.variables = {}
for value in l:
    self.variables[value] = Button()
```